# jQuery/AJAX Not Updating Record With Varchar ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This function works fine when the idInquiryItems is a number (1), but does not work when idInquiryItems includes letters (a3hcu45vn). When the id includes letters it doesn't even trigger the confirm popup.

```
function deleteRecord(idInquiryItems) {
if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line item?")) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "idInquiryItems=" + idInquiryItems,
        success: function(data){
          $("#table-row-"+idInquiryItems).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

}

idInquiryItems triggers Uncaught ReferenceError: a3hcu45vn is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (inquiry.php?idInquiry=1:156)

HTML

```
<table id="inquiry-item-grid" class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-border w3-white">
    <col width="50">
    <col width="50">
    <col width="50">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Line</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>UOM</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">

              <tr class="table-row" id="table-row-a3hcu45vn">
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Line" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Line','a3hcu45vn')" onClick="editRow(this);">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Quantity" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Quantity','a3hcu45vn')" onClick="editRow(this);">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="UOM" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'UOM','a3hcu45vn')" onClick="editRow(this);">ea</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Description" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Description','a3hcu45vn')" onClick="editRow(this);">test</td>
        <td><a class="ajax-action-links w3-right" style="padding-right: 16px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteRecord(a3hcu45vn);" title="Delete a3hcu45vn">X</a></td>
      </tr>
              <tr class="table-row" id="table-row-1">
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Line" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Line','1')" onClick="editRow(this);">5</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Quantity" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Quantity','1')" onClick="editRow(this);">1</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="UOM" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'UOM','1')" onClick="editRow(this);">ea</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" id="Description" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'Description','1')" onClick="editRow(this);">readreadread</td>
        <td><a class="ajax-action-links w3-right" style="padding-right: 16px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="deleteRecord(1);" title="Delete 1">X</a></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
require_once("config.php");
$pdo_statement=$pdo_conn->prepare("UPDATE InquiryItems SET Deleted = 1 WHERE idInquiryItems = '" . $_POST['idInquiryItems'] . "'");
$pdo_statement->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Does the javascript console give anny error(s) when using `a3hcu45vn`?.. You should also show the code of `php/delete.php`

Comment: If you do not even see the confirm messagebox, there probably is an error before that in your Javascript.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: a3hcu45vn is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (inquiry.php?idInquiry=1:156)"

Answer (score 0):

Try

processData: false,
data: "idInquiryItems=" + idInquiryItems,

Or

data:{
idInquiryItems: idInquiryItems
}

Answer (score 0):

Passing the id to the function wrapped in quotes fixed the issue!

```
deleteRecord('a3hcu45vn')
```